# Sorting an unnamed integer column in powershell

Tags: sorting, powershell

I'd lile to sort a csv in powershell that looks like this:

```
0.980242;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040793.JPG
0.167471;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040805.JPG
0.133792;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040808.JPG
0.616142;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040819.JPG
0.0485409;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040825.JPG
0.17998;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040826.JPG
0.0428832;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040837.JPG
0.713708;DATABASE_PICTURES/P7020228.JPG
1;DATABASE_PICTURES//P7020229.JPG
```

I want to sort the list from highest to lowest number in the first column -->

```
1;DATABASE_PICTURES//P7020229.JPG
0.980242;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040793.JPG
0.713708;DATABASE_PICTURES/P7020228.JPG
0.616142;DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040819.JPG
and so on
```

I tried this script

```
Import-CSV C:\xampp\htdocs\results\result.csv -Header ('foo', 'bar') -delimiter ';' | Sort-Object foo
```

but it just doesn't do anything. I've also researched half the internetz, but none of the given codes work or make sense to me. Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: sort {[double]$_.foo} -Descending

Comment: Ok, so it does sort it now(I am an idiot...int), but doesnt write it back into the file.

Comment: Ok, i found a workaround, nevermind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to get the answer in here since no one has up to this point.

The problem you are having is not that the sort is not working but that it is sorting alphabettically and not numerically like you would expect.

```
Foo                                                                                                                                                                         
---                                                                                                                                                                         
0.0428832                                                                                                                                                                   
0.0485409                                                                                                                                                                   
0.133792                                                                                                                                                                    
0.167471                                                                                                                                                                    
0.17998                                                                                                                                                                     
0.616142                                                                                                                                                                    
0.713708                                                                                                                                                                    
0.980242                                                                                                                                                                    
1
```

When all properties are imported using `Import-CSV` they are typed as string. Output from `Get-Member`

```
Bar         NoteProperty System.String Bar=DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040793.JPG
Foo         NoteProperty System.String Foo=0.980242
```

Depending on the other needs of your code you can simply use @PetSerAI's suggestion and cast it in the sort.

```
`| Sort-Object {[double]$_.Foo} -Descending`
```

If you have other things to do with that data it might be an advantage to change its type after the import so that you don't have to do multiple casts.

```
$data = Import-CSV C:\xampp\htdocs\results\result.csv -Header ('foo', 'bar') -delimiter ';' | 
    Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Foo @{Name="Foo";Expression={[double]$_.Foo}},* 
$data | Sort-Object foo -Descending
```

I will assume that you have more properties that just `foo` and `bar` so to make it so you don't have too retype all the properties you can just `-ExcludeProperty` the one that needs special attention and then used a Calculated property to cast the variable as `[double]`. Now you can `Sort` and get the expected results.

```
Bar         NoteProperty System.String Bar=DATABASE_PICTURES/P1040793.JPG
Foo         NoteProperty System.Double Foo=0.980242
```